# android - TextWatcher of EditText stops working well, after copying text from ListView to the EditText

Tags: android

I have a TextView named mSearchEdit.

i added a TextWatcher that if mSearchEdit changes, it looks in a parse.com server if there is a ParseObject "Products" that is feild "productName" contains the text. if there is, it returns 3 ParseObject "Products",and show there name it in a ListView. if the user presses on one of the ListView items, it changes the text of mSearchEdit to be like the item.

it works, but there is a bug:

if the user chooses a item (what puts the item text in the mSearchEdit), and then changes the text in the mSearchEdit, app continues running, but no query made to parse.com with no text. when i debug it, i could see that in this case,  it enters the "onTextChanged" function but the last line it runs in function is:

```
query.whereContains("productName", searchRegexText);
```

this is the code:

```
mSearchEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //textWatcher = this;
            String searchRegexText = mSearchEdit.getText().toString();
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Products");
            query.whereContains("productName", searchRegexText);
            query.setLimit(3);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    List<String> offers = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i< list.size();i++) {
                        offers.add((String)(list.get(i)).get("productName"));
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                            new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                                    R.layout.text1,
                                    android.R.id.text1,
                                    offers);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                            if (!mSearchEdit.getText().equals(item)){
                                mSearchEdit.setText(item);
                            }
                            listview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                });

                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```